# How to replace characters between two anchors?

Tags: regex, perl

If I have a string like so

```
my $s = 'src="/api/385/=VIGTIG%20UPDATE%20!.jpg?size=webview" /></span>';
```

How do I then replace all `%20` with `_` that are between `/api/385/` and the first `>` ?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Would it make sense to use a DOM parser?

Comment: It is html that have been converted to wiki mockup, so it is not valid html at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to write:

```
$s =~ s{(/api/385/[^>]*>)}{my $tmp = $1; $tmp =~ s/%20/_/g; $tmp}e;
```

which replaces `(/api/385/[^>]*>)` with the result of replacing `%20` with `_` inside it. (The `e` flag in an `s///` means "the replacement-stuff is an *expression*, not a *string literal*".)

Comment: The bracket notation `[...]` creates a "character class". Usually it means "any of the characters inside the brackets" -- for example, `[aeiou]` means "any of the characters `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`", and `[1-5M-Q]` means "any ASCII digit between `1` and `5` or ASCII uppercase letter between `M` and `Q`" -- but when the first character in a character class is `^`, it means the opposite; so `[^>]` means "any character that is *not* `>`". The asterisk `*` means "zero or more of what I just said (and more is better than fewer)", so `[^>]*` means "zero or more characters that are not `>`".

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want

```
$s =~ s|(/=[^>]+)| (my $ss = $1) =~ s/%20/_/g; $ss |e;
```

but are you aware that `%20` is hex for a space?